# Synchronize files between a mac server and a c# program?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, communication

I've data on a mac server, on which I've several files. 
I've to do a c# program which connect to the server and retrieve files which are different.

The server and the workstation will not be on the same network, so I need to have a secure access(the encryption is a plus, but it's mostly about other people cannot go read files on the server).

I taught of several things:

- Rsync over SSH(but I didn't found any good library on the .net server, which manage ssh and is recent enough)
- Samba(not secure enough?)/SFtp access(but I need to do myself the hash mecanism, check on dates, ...)

What is my best option? Do you have an other (better) idea?

Comment: http://sshnet.codeplex.com/ seems quite active...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely use Samba/CIFS. Why is this not secure enough? It is used by Windows operating systems (the MS implementation of it) all over the wolds, in enterprise systems.
Why do you think it is not secure enough?

Comment: I know it's very used, but I thought it was mostly used for internal network. Is there a way to encrypt the data transmission?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part that they were not on the same network. Maybe SSH (scp) is a better solution. There seems to be several libraries available for this, e.g. http://sshnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: I saw that there is the possibility to do some SFTP with this lib, but  what is exactly SFTP? Is there only a scp over ssh?